# Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to create a Bible App that somewhat displays the 4 Watches of Day and 4 Watches of Night with some pause in between.

My problem is: The starting points (sunset and sunrise) are not always taken exactly as put in the program. For instanse : When I put 18:00 sunset and 06:00 sunrise all is good. But when I put 20:46 sunset and 06:31 sunrise, the so called Bible App I'm having, is displaying the first Night or Day Watch not 20:46 and 06:31 as put, BUT 20:6 and 06:1, and of course the whole calculation is going south from there... I don't really get what's wrong with my pseudo app. Any help will be appreceated. Link to my JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/TeodorZhekov/cy23s6vw/

```js
// let sunset = prompt(`Enter Sunset: {HH:MM}.`);
let sunset = `20:46`;
let sunsetHH = Number(sunset.substr(0, 2));
let sunsetMM = Number(sunset.substr(4, 6));

// let sunrise = prompt(`Enter Sunrise: {HH:MM}.`);
let sunrise = `06:31`;
let sunriseHH = Number(sunrise.substr(0, 2));
let sunriseMM = Number(sunrise.substr(4, 6));

let difference = new Date(`2020/10/10 ${sunrise}`) - new Date(`2020/10/09 ${sunset}`);

let darkPart = Math.round((difference / 1000) / 60);

let darkHour = Math.round(darkPart / 4);
let darkHourRest = Math.round(darkHour / 6);
let darkHourWork = Math.round(darkHour - darkHourRest);

let lightPart = Math.round(1440 - darkPart);

let lightHour = Math.round(360 - darkHour);
let lightHourRest = Math.round(60 - darkHourRest);
let lightHourWork = Math.round(300 - darkHourWork);

// NIGHT WATCHES

// sunset
document.getElementById(`Sunset`).innerHTML = `Sunset - ${sunset}`;

// 1st Night Watch
let FirstNightWatchWork = new Date();
FirstNightWatchWork.setHours(sunsetHH, sunsetMM);
document.getElementById(`FirstNightWatchWork`).innerHTML = `1st Night Watch (Work) - ${FirstNightWatchWork.getHours()}:${FirstNightWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let FirstNightWatchRest = new Date();
FirstNightWatchRest.setHours(sunsetHH, (sunsetMM + (darkHour - darkHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`FirstNightWatchRest`).innerHTML = `1st Night Watch (Rest) - ${FirstNightWatchRest.getHours()}:${FirstNightWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;

// 2nd Night Watch
let SecondNightWatchWork = new Date();
SecondNightWatchWork.setHours(sunsetHH, (sunsetMM + darkHour));
document.getElementById(`SecondNightWatchWork`).innerHTML = `2nd Night Watch (Work) - ${SecondNightWatchWork.getHours()}:${SecondNightWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let SecondNightWatchRest = new Date();
SecondNightWatchRest.setHours(sunsetHH, (sunsetMM + ((darkHour * 2) - darkHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`SecondNightWatchRest`).innerHTML = `2nd Night Watch (Rest) - ${SecondNightWatchRest.getHours()}:${SecondNightWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;

// 3rd Night Watch
let ThirdNightWatchWork = new Date();
ThirdNightWatchWork.setHours(sunsetHH, (sunsetMM + (darkHour * 2)));
document.getElementById(`ThirdNightWatchWork`).innerHTML = `3rd Night Watch (Work) - ${ThirdNightWatchWork.getHours()}:${ThirdNightWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let ThirdNightWatchRest = new Date();
ThirdNightWatchRest.setHours(sunsetHH, (sunsetMM + ((darkHour * 3) - darkHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`ThirdNightWatchRest`).innerHTML = `3rd Night Watch (Rest) - ${ThirdNightWatchRest.getHours()}:${ThirdNightWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;

// 4th Night Watch
let FourthNightWatchWork = new Date();
FourthNightWatchWork.setHours(sunsetHH, (sunsetMM + (darkHour * 3)));
document.getElementById(`FourthNightWatchWork`).innerHTML = `4th Night Watch (Work) - ${FourthNightWatchWork.getHours()}:${FourthNightWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let FourthNightWatchRest = new Date();
FourthNightWatchRest.setHours(sunsetHH, (sunsetMM + ((darkHour * 4) - darkHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`FourthNightWatchRest`).innerHTML = `4th Night Watch (Rest) - ${FourthNightWatchRest.getHours()}:${FourthNightWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;

// DAY WATCHES

// Sunrise
document.getElementById(`Sunrise`).innerHTML = `Sunrise - ${sunrise}`;

// 1st Day Watch
let FirstDayWatchWork = new Date();
FirstDayWatchWork.setHours(sunriseHH, sunriseMM);
document.getElementById(`FirstDayWatchWork`).innerHTML = `1st Day Watch (Work) - ${FirstDayWatchWork.getHours()}:${FirstDayWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let FirstDayWatchRest = new Date();
FirstDayWatchRest.setHours(sunriseHH, (sunriseMM + (lightHour - lightHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`FirstDayWatchRest`).innerHTML = `1st Day Watch (Rest) - ${FirstDayWatchRest.getHours()}:${FirstDayWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;

// 2nd Day Watch
let SecondDayWatchWork = new Date();
SecondDayWatchWork.setHours(sunriseHH, (sunriseMM + lightHour));
document.getElementById(`SecondDayWatchWork`).innerHTML = `2nd Day Watch (Work) - ${SecondDayWatchWork.getHours()}:${SecondDayWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let SecondDayWatchRest = new Date();
SecondDayWatchRest.setHours(sunriseHH, (sunriseMM + ((lightHour * 2) - lightHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`SecondDayWatchRest`).innerHTML = `2nd Day Watch (Rest) - ${SecondDayWatchRest.getHours()}:${SecondDayWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;

// 3rd Day Watch
let ThirdDayWatchWork = new Date();
ThirdDayWatchWork.setHours(sunriseHH, (sunriseMM + (lightHour * 2)));
document.getElementById(`ThirdDayWatchWork`).innerHTML = `3rd Day Watch (Work) - ${ThirdDayWatchWork.getHours()}:${ThirdDayWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let ThirdDayWatchRest = new Date();
ThirdDayWatchRest.setHours(sunriseHH, (sunriseMM + ((lightHour * 3) - lightHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`ThirdDayWatchRest`).innerHTML = `3rd Day Watch (Rest) - ${ThirdDayWatchRest.getHours()}:${ThirdDayWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;

// 4th Day Watch
let FourthDayWatchWork = new Date();
FourthDayWatchWork.setHours(sunriseHH, (sunriseMM + (lightHour * 3)));
document.getElementById(`FourthDayWatchWork`).innerHTML = `4th Day Watch (Work) - ${FourthDayWatchWork.getHours()}:${FourthDayWatchWork.getMinutes()}`;

let FourthDayWatchRest = new Date();
FourthDayWatchRest.setHours(sunriseHH, (sunriseMM + ((lightHour * 4) - lightHourRest)));
document.getElementById(`FourthDayWatchRest`).innerHTML = `4th Day Watch (Rest) - ${FourthDayWatchRest.getHours()}:${FourthDayWatchRest.getMinutes()}`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bible Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BibleClock.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Sunset"></div>
    <div id="FirstNightWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="FirstNightWatchRest"></div>
    <div id="SecondNightWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="SecondNightWatchRest"></div>
    <div id="ThirdNightWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="ThirdNightWatchRest"></div>
    <div id="FourthNightWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="FourthNightWatchRest"></div>

    <div class="empty">---------------------------------</div>

    <div id="Sunrise"></div>
    <div id="FirstDayWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="FirstDayWatchRest"></div>
    <div id="SecondDayWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="SecondDayWatchRest"></div>
    <div id="ThirdDayWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="ThirdDayWatchRest"></div>
    <div id="FourthDayWatchWork"></div>
    <div id="FourthDayWatchRest"></div>

    <script src="BibleClock.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Write a title that summarizes the specific problem

Comment: How do I change the title? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: First thing, replace : `xxx.substr(4, 6)` by `xxx.substr(3, 2);` => as you can see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr, the format is `chn.substr(début[, longueur])` so for your sunset/sunriseMM you want the third char of HH:MM with lenght = 2 to get  MM

Comment: As @MickaëlLeger says, the *substr* indexes are wrong. But anyway, better to drop the substring stuff and use split, e.g. `let [h, m] = sunset.split(':')`.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ami ! C'était vraiment petit, mais je le voyais pas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do :

```
// let sunset = prompt(`Enter Sunset: {HH:MM}.`);
let sunset = `20:46`;
let sunsetHH = Number(sunset.substr(0, 2));
let sunsetMM = Number(sunset.substr(4, 6));

// let sunrise = prompt(`Enter Sunrise: {HH:MM}.`);
let sunrise = `06:31`;
let sunriseHH = Number(sunrise.substr(0, 2));
let sunriseMM = Number(sunrise.substr(4, 6));
```

What you get with `console.log(sunsetHH, sunsetMM, sunriseHH, sunriseMM);` : `20, 6, 6, 1`

Replace `xxx.substr(4, 6)` by `xxx.substr(3, 2)` and you will get what you want : `20, 46, 6, 31`

See documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

The format is `chn.substr(début[, longueur])` so for your sunset/sunriseMM you want the third char of HH:MM with lenght = 2 to get MM

Now as suggested in comment by RobG, you can just split your string :

```
let sunset = `20:46`;
let sunrise = `06:31`;

let [sunsetHH, sunsetMM] = sunset.split(':')
let [sunriseHH, sunriseMM] = sunrise.split(':')
```

Result is : `"20", "46", "06", "31"`

Comment: Merci ami, très gentil de ta part :)

Answer (score 0):

In you substract you consider start at 1 instead of 0.
See below.

// let sunset = prompt(`Enter Sunset: {HH:MM}.`);
let sunset = `20:46`;
let sunsetHH = Number(sunset.substr(0, 2));
**let sunsetMM = Number(sunset.substr(3, 5));**

// let sunrise = prompt(`Enter Sunrise: {HH:MM}.`);
let sunrise = `06:31`;
let sunriseHH = Number(sunrise.substr(0, 2));
**let sunriseMM = Number(sunrise.substr(3, 5));**

Comment: Thank you for the help! I got it now.

Comment: Cool, have fun !